# I'm getting 'Non-public member' when adding items in List - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a class Devices

```
public class Devices
{
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string valueY { get; set; }
    public string valueZ { get; set; }

}
```

and have a function

```
private void fillData(JArray arrData)
    {

        var data = new List<Devices>();

        for(int i = 0; i<arrData.Count; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new Devices
            {
                nombre = "X",
                valueY = "Y",
                valueZ = "Z"
            });
        }

        list.ItemsSource = data;
    }
```

When check 'data' I just have 'Non-public members' instead of real values.

Please help.

[image: Log - data]

Comment: is this a compile error or a run time exception?  Which specific line is causing the error, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: A run time exception

Comment: It says just such frase in list

Comment: Can you replace JArray by .NET collection?

Comment: I change to ArrayList, but it does not recognise it, even using .NET collection

Comment: when you say "non public member" I think you are looking at the debug/immediate window (or something) NOT actually viewing an exception.  You are not doing a very good job of describing the problem you're having

Comment: Excume if I can't be clear with this, my english is not good enough. I just have that in List instead of 'X','Y','Z' as values

Comment: then please post a screenshot

Comment: I already added an image to the question showing the inspection view

Comment: I think you're getting distracted by some weird behavior by the debugger that has nothing to do with your actual app

Comment: Thanks anyway, I continue searching for a solution, even using another method

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?  If you Console.Writeline(data[0].nombre), does work?

Comment: Very interesting. I just tried using the Devices class and looping 3 times to put items in data. I was able to see X, Y, and Z without any problem.

Comment: I think your code should work. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding and restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: I have this exact problem. A class, with all public properties during runtime show as non-public members. When attempting serialization the result is an empty string. Allegedly you might get results by changing the linking settings to SDK Assemblies only, though it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `arrData.Count` is 0 and the loop never iterated. Check the `arrData`. It would add items if you set const limit for loop.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        data.Add(new Devices
        {
            nombre = "X",
            valueY = "Y",
            valueZ = "Z"
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I have 5 devices and the loop iterated 5 times adding 5 items with 'Non-public member' values in 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access the  `data` from `ViewModel`. `Non-public member` simply mean that the `access modifier` is not public. In your case it is `private`. Try changing it to public.